# Remove background of image containing text

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am building custom ocr for some documents. After getting ROI I am passing them to tesseract. To improve accuracy I want to remove background of image. I am observing that when there are images like this:
[image]

[image]

tesseract is not able to read anything.(Because of lines in the image)

But for images like this:[image] Its giving correct results.
Can any one suggest how to remove everything from image except text?

Comment: An heuristic approach would be to keep only the color of the text (and possibly a small region around them) and make the remaining white for example. Not sure it will work though.

Comment: That might work. Any guide how to do that?

Comment: @Eypros Loved the nerd calculator on your profile. You should start with thresholding the image to see if you can get rid of the colors.

Comment: I tried thresolding but I am getting B&W image with those lines in it